# Meaning of parens around number

Tags: c

This is a snippet of C code from a library:

```
typedef enum
{
/** 
  * @brief  SDIO specific error defines  
  */   
  SD_CMD_CRC_FAIL                    = (1), /*!< Command response received (but CRC check failed) */
  SD_DATA_CRC_FAIL                   = (2), /*!< Data bock sent/received (CRC check Failed) */
  SD_CMD_RSP_TIMEOUT                 = (3), /*!< Command response timeout */
  SD_DATA_TIMEOUT                    = (4), /*!< Data time out */
```

I do not understand the meaning of the parens around `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. Are `SD_CMD_CRC_FAIL = 1` and `SD_CMD_CRC_FAIL = (1)` equivalent?

Comment: Just for future reference, those aren't brackets. They're parentheses, normally shortened to 'parens' when programming. Brackets are `[]`, and braces are `{}`. (It helps when you're talking about programming to be using the same terminology.) :)

Comment: Maybe the author of the code thought that makes it negative...? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.

I don't know why the author chose to write it like that (although see the comments to this answer for some theories).

Comment: The commenting format looks like a Javadoc tag, maybe the author is used to enums in Java.

Comment: Maybe that's the output of some macro or other source generating *thing*.

Comment: Maybe it was converted (rather mechanically) from a set of macros to an enum at some point.  Such syntax would be common for macros.

Comment: It's just one of the possible ways to define a doxygen description inside the same line as the definition (just assuming doxygen is used).

Comment: @FatalError's theory sounds likely, especially since the doc comment mentions "defines"

Answer (score 3):

Brackets around single values are optional and there's no hidden magic attached. `(1)` will just evaluate to `1` if it's not part of some function call (i.e. delimiting parameters).

It's like in math, where you can add several levels of brackets without changing the meaning of an expression such as `x = ((5) + (3))`.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses make no difference in this particular case, but it's a good idea to **always** surround macro expressions with a pair of parentheses. Author of the code probably  converted macro definitions into the `enum`, and parens remained as a leftover from the old code.

---

As an aside, here's the reason for this rule. Consider the following code:

```
#define FOUR 2 + 2
...
int x = 2 * FOUR;
```

The last line will be converted by the preprocessor into `int x = 2 * 2 + 2;` and will evaluate to 6 instead of 8, as you would expect. This wouldn't occur if `FOUR` was defined with surrounding parens:

```
#define FOUR (2 + 2)
```